# operator[]= overload?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, brackets

Okay, I'm trying to make a quick little class to work as a sort of hash table.  If I can get it to work then I should be able to do this:

```
  StringHash* hash = new StringHash;
  hash["test"] = "This is a test";
  printf(hash["test"]);
```

And it should print out "This is a test".

It looks like I have 2 problems at this point.  Firstly I did this:

```
const char* operator[](const char* key) {
  for(int i = 0; i < hashSize; ++i) {
    if(strcmp(hkeys[i], key) == 0) {return values[i];}
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

But when I try to look up a value the compiler complains that

error: invalid types `StringHash*[const char[5]]' for array subscript

Secondly operator[]= does not appear to be the correct syntax here.  The only other thing I could find was &operator[] but I don't think that will work since I have to code the lookup procedure???  (Isn't that syntax just used to return an array item reference?)

Is what I'm trying to do here even possible?  Any advice appreciated.  :)

---

Seems to be some confusion about what I'm trying to do.  I'll post my code:

http://pastebin.com/5Na1Xvaz

---

Finished product after all the help:

http://pastebin.com/gx4gnYy8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would firstly question why you are writing your own HashMap when there are some versions available albeit not a standard one. *(that was written in 2010, but there is now std::unordered_map)*

Does your hash-map store const char* pointers or std::strings? (It might store const char * pointers if it is simply a lookup table to data stored elsewhere that is not going to change its lifetime).

What is operator[] supposed to do when the item is not found?

Now let me assume that the answers are:

- Yes we are storing const char * pointers, and we store a NULL in an empty cell
- When we perform hash[key]=value we want to associate key with value
- If we just do hash[key] but don't write, it does not insert

This can be done with a magic object: when you assign a const char * to this object it inserts or overwrites to the hash. You can also have an implicit conversion from the object to const char * for reading.

This is quite complex though and it is preferable to stick to the regular interface of map: operator[] always inserts and you use a different method just to lookup.

Comment: Hmm...  I think I understand what you're saying.  You want me to write a class with an operator=() and then have that handle adding the entry to the table, yes?  I can see that working.  The thing I'm worried about though, wouldn't I have to store another array internally that would hold an instance of that class for every...  Ah, no wait.  I could just use those objects as the internal values instead of const char* and then have them return the string on lookup.  Got it.  :)

Comment: Shoot.  It won't let me do it this way.  It keeps trying to return the magic object instead of the cstring.

Comment: You can define an implicit conversion between the "magic" type and `const char*`. Using `std::strings` is a more robust solution, though.

Comment: Yeah.  That's where I'm stuck.  How do I define an implicit conversion to const char*?  I'm trying to find info on that now.

Comment: I found a site that says to use 'operator const char*()'.  I'm trying to fiddle with that now.  (Never seen a type as an operator before.)

Comment: Okay.  Now it works, which is awesome, but it also core dumps when main() returns.  ARGH...  Maybe a problem with the dtors...  :(

Anyway, thank you all!  :)

Comment: Works perfectly now!  This is why I re-invent the wheel, btw.  I unexpectedly learned several new things just writing this small class!  Thanks again to everybody.  :)

Comment: Now you have done that your next exercise is to make it const-correct. For that to happen, if you have a const reference to your hash table it will let you read but not insert. Hint: operator[] should have two overloads, and the const-one gives you a genuine const char *.

Answer (score 7):

The error is because `hash` is a pointer. Change to:

```
StringHash hash;
```

Comment: Good catch.  Thank you.  It's not giving a compile error there now.  Initial test works, so I can look up values in the hash by their keys now.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers relate to your first question. As for your second...

If you return a reference, then you're returning an lvalue. You can always assign to an lvalue.

Yes, it (pretty much) really is that simple. I recommend reading carefully for whether or not you need `const` in various places, though.

What I remember reading is that you should provide a `const` and a non-`const` overload for `operator[]`, something like so:

```
MyType const &operator[](int index) const; // This is the array access version (no assignment allowed), which should work on const objects
MyType &operator[](int index);      // This is the array access or assignment version, which is necessarily non-const.
```

See this link for more information.

Answer (score 3):

`hash` isn't a `StringHash` object.  Its a pointer to one.

You can do this:

`(*hash)["test"] = "This is a test";`

Or you can ask yourself why you need a pointer to it in the first place,

```
StringHash hash;
hash["test" = "This is a test";
```

... or even if you do, why you wouldn't use a smart pointer like `auto_ptr`.

```
#include <memory>
std::auto_ptr<StringHash> hash( new StringHash );
(*hash)["test"] = "This is a test";
```

Answer (score 3):

Write `StringHash hash;` instead of the `new` thing. C++ isn't Java. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The first error is that you declared hash to be a pointer. Pointer types can already be used with the index operator. For example, pointer[3] is equivalent to *(pointer+3). You can't change that behaviour. Make hash the object itself:

```
StringHash sh;
```

As for operator[]=, there is no such thing. Your index operator should just return a reference in order to make the assignment work. Here's a simple example of how this would look like:

```
class Indexable
{
   std::string arr[3];
public:
   std::string & operator[](int index) {
      return arr[index];
   }
   std::string const& operator[](int index) const {
      return arr[index];
   }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Five problems:

1. `hash` is a pointer to a StringHash, you have to dereference it to use operators: `(*hash)["test"]`
2. If you want to assign to the element, you have to return a reference to the element type

   `const char *& operator[] (const char* key);`

   `// ...`

   `(*hash)["test"] = "This is a test"; // will compile now`
3. `null` isn't a keyword in C++. Use 0 or `NULL`.
4. `operator []` has to allocate space for an element if it isn't found. Returning `NULL` isn't an option. Otherwise, trying to assign to the result of `(*hash)["test"]` will crash your program.
5. Use std::map or std::tr1::unordered_map instead of writing your own "quick" class.

And just to be a jerk: You know that isn't a hash table, right?

Comment: 1. Fixed. ty
2. I'm trying to overload the element assignment because I want to strcpy the rval.
3. Noticed that just after I posted. Fixed. ty
4. See 2.
5. Don't wanna. :)

Why is it not a hash table?

Comment: @ddd: It's not a hash table because it doesn't calculate the keys' hash values in order to index into the array. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: Ah.  I see what you mean.  A regular table then I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use a `boost::unordered_map<std::string, std::string`? Then you don't have to worry about implementing this on your own.

Assuming it's an exercise of some sort for yourself:
You may come from different background, but in C++ the normal way to declare your hash would be:

```
StringHash hash;
```

Additionally your `operator[]` might work for the print but it won't work for the assignment. Normally `operator[]` methods work by returning a non-const reference or a proxy object to which the new values can be assigned, and yours does neither. If you were able to use std::string, you could rewrite your method to return a non-const reference to the position within the hash that should be read or assigned.